# Delete a specific occurrence of an integer in multiple lists at once. Python

Tags: python

```
mike = [1, 2, 3, 4,]
john = [2, 3, 4, 5,]
adam = [3, 4, 5, 6,]
joey = [4, 5, 6, 7,]

employees = [mike, john, adam, joey]
```

When an element from the employees list is removed, how would you delete the variable with the same name, and a specific element in all of the lists?

For example, if [mike] was removed from 'employees'...the mike variable needs to be deleted, and the integer "1" deleted from ALL of the lists.

Comment: '1' isn't in any of the other lists.  Perhaps give a realistic example with inputs and expected otuputs?

Comment: can you post your code please? so we can review it and help if we can. its seems to me like home work.

Comment: You may wish to look at python's `dict` type: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: I reckon this is asking for a tree/graph structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:-

```
mike = [1, 2, 3, 4,]
john = [2, 3, 4, 5,]
adam = [3, 4, 5, 6,]
joey = [4, 5, 6, 7,]

employees = [mike, john, adam, joey]
def drop_list(list_of_list,list_to_delete):
    list_of_list.remove(list_to_delete)
    new_list_of_list = list()
    for l in list_of_list:
        l = [x for x in l if x not in list_to_delete]
        new_list_of_list.append(l)
    return new_list_of_list
employees = drop_list(employees,mike)
print(employees)
```

Output:-

```
[[5], [5, 6], [5, 6, 7]]
```

Hope this helps!!